# How to reset semantic Ui form?

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I read semantic form validation docs, and as far as I understand the form should be reset with button reset class and with jQuery form reset method But nothing seems to work for me.

I tried capturing the form with class but it didn't work.
Here is my code

HTML

```
<form id="ticker_create_form" action="" class="ui form ticker_create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" value="ticker" name="type">

                <div id="" class="ui segments ntf_view_state">
                    <div class="ui segment">
                        <div class="ui checked checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ntf_inside" value="inside" name="view_location[]">
                            <label>Inside (Dashboard)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui segment">
                        <div class="ui checked checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ntf_outside" value="outside"
                                   name="view_location[]">
                            <label>Outside</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Description -->
                <div id="" class="field ntf_description">
                    <label for="">Description</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Provide description (max of 600 characters)"
                              name="description"></textarea>
                </div>
                        </div>

                <div class="field ntf_btns">
                    <button id="add_ticker_btn" class=" positive large ui button ntf_btn" type="button">ADD TICKER
                        NOTIFICATION
                    </button>
                    <button id="reset_ticker_btn" class="negative large ui reset button ntf_btn" type="button">RESET
                        FORM
                    </button>
                </div>

            </form>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.ui.reset.button').on('click', function(){
            $('.ui.form.ticker_create').form('reset');
     });
});
```

Comment: This should help $('.ui.form.ticker_create').form('clear');

Comment: yes, it's working. But I want to reset my form not to clear as I have some default values too in my form

Comment: This solution works for me $('.ui.form.ticker_create')[0].reset();
I do not know why but it does not work for me either $('form').form('reset')